# SQL subtracting values from two different tables in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two different tables that contain one value each. For example:

```
    table1               table2

|Hours_worked|        |Work_Completed|
     250                    346
```

I want my query to subtract Hours_worked from Work_completed. I tried this:

```
SELECT (SELECT Hours_worked FROM table1)- (SELECT Work_Completed FROM table2) AS Diff
```

I get the error: "Query input must contain at least one table or query"

Any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would just be:

```
select Hours_worked - Work_Completed as diff
from table1, table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add FROM dual, i mean:

```
 SELECT 
 (SELECT Hours_worked FROM table1) - (SELECT Work_Completed FROM table2) AS Diff
 FROM DUAL
```

Comment: This assumes that the OP has a dual table, which does not exist by default.